# Requests for Reopening

Tags: discussion, feature-request

In view of and pursuant to the multitudinous requests here for reopenings, I thought about adapting a modality from Math Meta SE (http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/6424) :

Would it help amalgamate, coalesce, and keep them all into one thread?
I'm happy to rewrite this to  enact and institute it here.

Comment: I can see arguments for both sides: it allows for easier reopening requests which won't clutter the meta site; it's not clear that it will be obvious to users to use the one meta question for reopen request. I'd like to see opinions from the mods, since they will have to deal with whatever mess either might cause.

Comment: I think the answer is transparentaneous, especially ever since Sartre suggested the use of nationalism to read and modify language. Basically you are faced with a choice: either reject structuralist discourse or conclude that government is capable of significance. This subject is interpolated into a textual libertarianism that includes narrativity as a totality. Therefore, any number of dematerialisms concerning the paradigm, and some would say the dialectic, of subtextual class exist. Derrida uses the term ‘predialectic deconstruction’ to denote this, and other things. Hope that ellucidates!

Comment: To the OP: If you are using words to form an impenetrable thatch that hinders communication, congratulations. Short of that, you might want to simply say what you mean. Trust me: nobody here is impressed by thesaurus mining.

Answer (score 4):

No, please don't.

One reason is that it's entirely new here. Another reason is that it allows each question to be discussed on its own merits: the Meta question proposes re-opening, and that can be voted on; and answers can either support that proposition (and gain upvotes) or stand against it (and gain upvotes for **that** stance). Answers can give reasons for siding in one direction or the other.

There is of course, the option simply to vote to re-open the Main question in point without commenting one way or the other; but that option exists however attention is drawn to the question. Arguably, questions on the main site are more likely to be re-opened more quickly if each is a separate Meta question, because those who can cast re-open votes don't have to search through a composite Meta question to find the most recent addition: the relevant Main question is itself pushed to the top of the Meta "active" list.

My name has a diamond here, but this answer has not been considered by other moderators. However, I don't consider that the proposal makes life easier for anyone, moderator or ordinary voter-member.

Comment: I'm another mod and I endorse this message. ;-)